# Why can't I flag a post as duplicate of the question with upvoted and accepted answer?

Tags: support

I wanted to mark [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303214/process-builder-workflow-trigger) question as a duplicate of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146369/understanding-order-of-execution) one, which has upvoted and accepted answer. However, it's not possible - I cannot find this question, picrel below:

[image]

Can someone please explain me the reason of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I got the same behavior. Instead, just copy-paste the URL into the search box (or the share link), or just the post number (146369), and that would allow you to find the question. P.S. I've gone ahead and done this for you.